# IQueryable Union with ViewModel does not work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two queries that return the same `IQueryable` viewmodel.

This is my first query:

```
var tempAfter = (from operation in _br_WarehouseOperation_GetAll.GetAll()
                 select new CardexSummaryViewModel
                         {
                             SumFirstImport = 0,
                             SumFirstExport = 0,
                             SumExport = g.Where(t => exportTypes == t.operation.TransactionTypeId).Sum(t => t.operationDetail.Quantity * t.operationDetail.UnitOfMeasure.ConversionFactor),
                             SumImport = g.Where(t => importTypes.Contains(t.operation.TransactionTypeId)).Sum(t => t.operationDetail.Quantity * t.operationDetail.UnitOfMeasure.ConversionFactor),
                             WarehouseGoodsId = warehouseGoods.WarehouseGoodsId,
                             SumPriceFirstImport = 0,
                             SumPriceFirstExport = 0,
                             SumPriceExport = g.Where(t => isPricing && exportTypes == t.operation.TransactionTypeId).Sum(t => t.operationDetail.WarehouseTransactionOperationPricings.Sum(it => it.TotalPrice)),
                             SumPriceImport = g.Where(t => isPricing && importTypes.Contains(t.operation.TransactionTypeId)).Sum(t => t.operationDetail.WarehouseTransactionOperationPricings.Sum(it => it.TotalPrice)),
                         });
```

and this is second query :

```
var tempBefore = (from operation in _br_WarehouseOperation_GetAll.GetAll()
                  select new CardexSummaryViewModel
                              {
                                  SumFirstImport = g.Where(t => importTypes.Contains(t.operation.TransactionTypeId)).Sum(t => t.operationDetail.Quantity * t.operationDetail.UnitOfMeasure.ConversionFactor),
                                  SumFirstExport = g.Where(t => exportTypes == t.operation.TransactionTypeId).Sum(t => t.operationDetail.Quantity * t.operationDetail.UnitOfMeasure.ConversionFactor),
                                  SumExport = 0,
                                  SumImport = 0,
                                  WarehouseGoodsId = warehouseGoods.WarehouseGoodsId,

                                  SumPriceFirstImport = g.Where(t => isPricing && importTypes.Contains(t.operation.TransactionTypeId))
                                            .Sum(t => t.operationDetail.WarehouseTransactionOperationPricings.Sum(it => it.TotalPrice)),
                                  SumPriceFirstExport = g.Where(t => isPricing && exportTypes == t.operation.TransactionTypeId)
                                            .Sum(t => t.operationDetail.WarehouseTransactionOperationPricings.Sum(it => it.TotalPrice)),
                                  SumPriceExport = 0,
                                  SumPriceImport = 0,
                              });
```

I want to union these two queries into one database call like this :

```
 tempAfter = tempBefore.Union(tempAfter);
 cardexSummery = tempAfter.ToList();
```

but it does not work and duplicates the rows.

I was wondering if anybody could tell me where I am missing something. Thanks

Comment: Apparently it looks like you have disjoint sets of data in two objects. By disjoint I mean that different values for all the property are being set explicitly. And if that is the case, the `union` operator will always return two rows for one `WarehouseGoodsId`, and those two rows are not duplicate, if that is what you mean by duplicate.

Comment: @SayanPal thanks for the comment. you are right. i checked my code again and realised there is a computed type property in my viewModel that compute its value by others. that was the reason that union returns two rows for WarehouseGoodsId

Answer (score 0):

Both linq statements are creating new CardexSummaryViewModel instances. Since hey are distinct instances the Union statement is doing it's job. You would need to provide all the equality checks/overrides in this class to determine if the instances are actually equal. Then the Union would filter out duplicates. It would still be possible to have two instances from one of the linq statements be equal, in which case, the Union would not filter those out, only equal objects from the two different statements. So, you would still want to use Distinct() after Union if you want all duplicates removed.